# Meaning of "Refute"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

From a word choice question:

> Researchers have not found the exact cause of hypnic jerks yet. Some claim that the nerves in
> the limbs send incorrect signals. Others **refute** it by suggesting that the brain misinterprets the
> relaxing muscles as encountering some danger, so it signals the muscles to twitch. Despite different
> hypotheses, they agree that sleep deprivation, fatigue, stress and anxiety, intense exercise, and brain
> stimulants may trigger a sleep start.

Is "refute" an appropriate word choice in the passage above? Or is it too strong since it suggests actively trying to prove the first hypothesis wrong?

Comment: (A) In this Case , that is just a claim without Proof. Hence Prove & refute may not be suitable. (B) Consider claim versus Counterclaim : "Others counter that claim by suggesting ...." (C) Alternatives are "oppose that claim" & "disagree with that claim".

Comment: I have checked multiple dictionaries to ensure that my answer, below, is correct. They all agree that 'refute' can mean to simply dispute or deny something. It seems people are taking the first definition and assuming it is the only one.

Comment: Since there is clearly some dispute over whether it means deny I would suggest it is safer to avoid its use in favour of the suggestions by @Prem

Comment: @mdewey true. I was confused by the dictionaries too when I looked up the word before posting this question. I thought "refute" can only mean "disprove".

Answer (score -1):

It's a reasonable word to use, it can simply mean 'disagree with'.

e.g. "I say that curry is the best food ever" : "I refute that, pasta is".

The sentence that forms your example is faulty, though, because what is being refuted is 'a claim', whereas in the sentence 'claim' is used as a verb, and you do not refute verbs.

Comment: That's not what 'refute' means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refute, "to *say* or prove that a person, statement, opinion, etc. is wrong or false". You could hardly get a clearer agreement that my definition is one of those that are correct.

Comment: I am aware that "refute" can mean "to deny the truth or accuracy of" according to the dictionaries. In fact that's what confused me, since I've seen "refute" used as "disprove" in the past.

Comment: I think the question is how common is "refute" used simply as "disagree with". If that usage is rare and if to most people refute simply means "disprove", then "refute" will not be a appropriate word to use.

Comment: @PRL75 yeah it's now sort of a prescriptivist vs descriptivist thing

Comment: And I'd rather be a descriptivist and see how "refute" is normally used and normally understood. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: @john *"I think the question is how common" * I really can't agree with that. What that effectively says is that the more knowledgeable people - those who know of the multiple definitions, are incorrect, simply because others don't know of, or don't care to use the alternative definition. As we all know, language evolves over time, and it is almost certainly because of this that some dictionaries have caught up with the 'new' deny, definition, and others haven't.

Comment: I'm not as concerned about correctness as about appropriateness -- whether the word will do it's job at conveying intended meanings to the reader. Language evolves and different groups use words in different ways. There's no good reason to say that one is correct and one is not. The only meaningful question is whether the word will be understood as the writer's intended meaning by the intended audience.

Comment: @John *"And I'd rather be a descriptivist"* And it is precisely because of descriptivists that some dictionaries now include the 'new' (it's apparently been happening for a century or so) meaning. We (native speakers) mainly learn words through exposure in context, and for many decades I've understood the 'deny' meaning. The first time I've ever looked 'refute' up was before giving my answer. Had I looked up the word in one of the dictionaries that did not allow that meaning, I'd probably have felt somewhat confused and left the question to someone else.

Comment: @PRL75 cool. Then I'm the one who should catch up with the new meanings. Thanks!

Comment: But still many might be confused if they don't know that "refute" can mean "disagree".

Comment: @john "I'm not as concerned about correctness as about appropriateness " Unfortunately, it's not that simple. You cannot tell people that they used a word 'inappropriately', if they are using a definition that appears in multiple dictionaries. I think a better word for what you want is 'unambiguous'. It's best not to use new definitions if you wish to be unambiguous, and believe that many people are unaware of them, and think their use is more restrictive.

Comment: Yes, unambiguous is more precise. So you think most people only know the more restrictive sense of "refute"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140260/discussion-between-john-and-prl75).